# Access Runtime 2007 Ucase-Function fails, solution or help in error tracking needed

Tags: ms-access, runtime

I am running a Access 2007 database which is filled by users which only have Access 2007 Runtime. 
The application was initially developed on WinXP and Acess 2007, now I am on Win7 and Access 2007.

Since I resaved the application, every client using XP encounters an error whenever the Ucase function is called.

For debugging purposes, I changed the Load-Sub of the main form to the single statement

```
bla = Ucase("foo")
```

Which brings the clients to the error message that there was a runtime error and the application has been halted.

I included error handling in the sub making it look like this:

```
    On Error GoTo handle
    bla = UCase("foo")
handle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
```

Strange enough, the handle is being ignored by the runtime.

The problem DOESN'T show up on any client with either a full Access 2007 or Windows 7 installation.

I am a bit confused how the windows version has anything to do with it.

Any help to either solve the problem or Tipps to get to a specific error code would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

tannerli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, when standard functions start throwing errors, it's because there's a broken reference to something.  When any reference is broken, then *all* references fail, even for the standard libraries.  Chances are, you have managed to reference to a newer version of one of the libraries that is not available on Windows XP.

Comment: You were right, along with my new PC there also came an installation of Office 2010. I referenced the Excel Library to generate reports. So any client without Excel 2010 would have the problem. I installed Excel 2003 and changed the reference to the Excel Library 11.0 which also provides the needed functions. What a strange error behaviour though... Thanks a lot

Comment: @tannerli This is the main reason that late binding to external libraries is recommended. Had you used late binding for Excel, it would have happily used the version it found and all would have been well.

Comment: @Remou Thanks, I wasn't aware of the difference and implications of the different binding methods, I will keep it in mind for future use